# Different colored segmented lines imagej

Tags: imagej

I'm trying to make assign colors to individual segmented lines using ROI Manager. Every time I make a selection and change the color in properties, the line reverts to its original color as soon as I click back on my image. How can I assign colors to individual lines and get them to stick? Thanks

Comment: If it matters:  ImageJ Version 1.53g, Java 1.8.0_172 (64-bit), macOS 10.12.6

Comment: A very similar question was asked and discussed on the [image.sc forum](https://forum.image.sc/t/segmented-lines-with-different-colors/48528?u=imagejan), and the regression was fixed with ij version 1.53i2. In any case, please always disclose when cross-posting on different channels, so others having the same issue can follow along.